# In a handlebars template, get the Ember controller from an each loop

Tags: ember.js

I have an each loop that looks something like this:

```
{{#each controller}}
  {{#link-to 'searches.show' this}}
    <span>{{name}}</span>
  {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

At the moment, the `this` in `{{#link-to 'searches.show' this}}` seems to refer to the content of the controller, rather than to the controller itself. Is there a way to pass in the controller here, rather than its model?

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#each}}
  {{#link-to 'searches.show' controller}}
    <span>{{name}}</span>
  {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

This will work fine.